# Trying to make a slider that contains text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a slider. My divs are #foo, #bar and #text.

`#foo` is the container div

`#bar` is a colored div inside `#foo`. It fills it with variable percentage width.

`#text` is a transparent div inside `#foo` (except for the text). It should be above `#bar`.

[Something like this (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA0lp.jpg)

How can I achieve this with CSS? My code currently looks something like this:

```css
#foo {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#bar {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#text {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="text">
    Some text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried in CSS? Where did you run into issues? This is quite simple and if you are asking this question, maybe you could try to read up on CSS a bit first? Its as simple as a relative box with two absolute boxes in it...

Comment: And for future posts, consider making the id's descriptive.

Comment: @JordanS Apart from the `#foo` the ids are actually pretty accurate :) `bar` just looks like stock, but in this context I think its an actually bar!

Comment: Added jsfiddle @somethinghere

Comment: If there's still anything unclear, let me know.

Comment: @somethinghere haha, I realized that bar happens to work right after I sent that... but.. I'm one for being descriptive when you can.

Comment: @JordanS Totally agree, and the `foo bar` thing cant help here.

Comment: is this the kind of things you try to o ? http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yeNbBo (about mix-blend-mode) rgba version http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/bBdyG

Answer (score 0):

Simple make the outer box positioned `relative` so child elements are *relative* to the outer box, then position both those elements `absolute`  inside their parent. Give the two inner boxes a position of top left. Now your z-index will work, check out this modified snippet:

```css
#foo {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

/* Combined these since they share a lot in common */
#bar, #text {
  /* Made width and height 100% as they are relative to the parent size now */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

#bar {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
}

#text {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="text">
        Some text.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
#slider {
  width: 200px;  
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

#percentage {
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

#bar {
  width: 75%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div id="bar">
  </div>
  <div id="percentage">75%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will fill the loading bar on hover - you may wish to use jQuery for a wider range of event handlers:

```
    <div id="foo">
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <div id="text">
            Some text.
        </div>
    </div>



    #foo {
      background: green;
      width: 100px;
      height: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;

    }

    #bar {
      background: red;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 2;
      transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    #text {
      z-index: 3;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }


    /* REMOVE BELOW AND EDIT #bar LEFT: VALUE FOR STATIC LOADING BAR */

    #foo:hover #bar{
      left: 100%;
    }
```